# azure unable to reuse subscription in devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-subscription

I created a new azure account, created a subscription and added a vm + DB to it.
I also created a DevOps organization and I am trying to add same subscription to DevOps org billing. But not sure why I am getting an error?

[image]

Please note: the subscription is active
see details of the subscription type
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a billing/subscription support issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note to check the type of your subscription and make sure it's not a free subscription.

> **Q:** What types of Azure subscriptions can I use to buy Azure DevOps?
>
> **A:** Almost all Azure subscriptions. We support Azure subscriptions connected to your [Enterprise Agreement](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/enterprise-agreement/) (EA), Azure subscriptions
> set up by Cloud Solution Providers (CSPs), through Microsoft Open
> License resellers, and Pay-As-You-Go. You can also buy using Azure
> subscriptions that Visual Studio subscribers set up as a subscriber
> benefit. (But no, your monthly credit can't be used pay for more
> Visual Studio subscriptions.) The only notable exclusion is that you
> can't use the [Azure free trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/free-trial/), Government, or National clouds.

Besides, if you have used a paid sub, please report your issue to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem).

Comment: guess you are right , I updated the question with subscription details , it doesnt mention a type anywhere , but it definitely says how much free credit is left